# Preprocessor Macros arn't set for some targets

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've run into an issue with defining preprocessor macros for different build targets.

I'm adding distinct flags to the *Build Settings* for each of the targets by setting *Preprocessor Macros* for all configurations to `$(inherit)` and `SOME_FLAG`, where `SOME_FLAG` may be different for each target. This works fine for most of my targets, but not for all. I've tried restarting Xcode, cleaning the targets and repeating the procedure above for other targets (which work).

In the project level build settings I only have `DEBUG=1` for the debug config.

I'm totally at a loss, so any hints on where to start looking are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the target-level build settings are not overriding the values?  Within the build settings you can normally see what settings are inherited from the project-level settings; verify they are correct.

Comment: I hopefully clarified my question. The whole point is to set the macros at target-level, and they do look correct. However the aren't visible to the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gave up on the broken targets and ended up recreating them, which fixed my problem.